# ArrayList partially overwrites stored values (but not all of them) when adding new object to the list (object variables aren´t static)

Tags: java, arraylist, domparser

First of all English is not my first language, so sorry in advance for the mistakes.

The thing is I need some help understanding why I´m overwriting some values inside my array list.

I know this question has been asked before but all solutions I found about this issue are related to variables declared static when they shouldn´t be, which I think is not my case.

The code is searching in two different .xml documents for pop songs contained in a especific album, and returning the array with the title and genres of each song.

First I have a Song defined as:

```
public class Song {
    private String title;
    private ArrayList<String> genre;
    public Song (String t, ArrayList<String> g) {
        title = t;
        genre = g;
    }
    public String getTitle () { return title; }
    public ArrayList<String> getGenre () { return genre; }
}
```

Then I´m searching trough the .xml documents for the required album and country.
It correctly finds the songs and the genres, but I´m having trouble adding them into an array.
The code is the following:
In this example the required album is called "titulo5" and thecountry is "england".

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    private static ArrayList<Song> Songs = new ArrayList<Song>();
    static DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    static DocumentBuilder db;
    static {
        try {
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

        String nextURL = run("tmvl_01.xml","england","titulo5");
        nextURL = run(nextURL,"england","titulo5");

    }
    private static String run(String filename, String country, String album)throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException
    {
        String nextURL = null;
        ArrayList<String> auxArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        try
        {
            Document doc = db.parse(new File(filename));
            Boolean test = false;

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("Album");
            Element elem;

            for (int x=0; x < nl.getLength(); x++)
            {
                elem = (Element)nl.item(x);
                NodeList nlTitles = elem.getElementsByTagName("Titulo");
                NodeList nlSongs = elem.getElementsByTagName("Song");
                Element elemAlbumTitle = (Element)nlTitles.item(0);
                String albumName = elemAlbumTitle.getTextContent().trim();
                if (albumName.equals(album)){
                    for(int i= 0; i < nlSongs.getLength();i++)
                    {
                        Element elemSongs = (Element)nlSongs.item(i);
                        NodeList nlSongTitle = elem.getElementsByTagName("Title");
                        Element elemSongTItle = (Element) nlSongTitle.item(i);
                        String songTItle = elemSongTItle.getTextContent().trim();
                        NodeList nlGenre = elemSongs.getElementsByTagName("Genre");
                        auxArray.clear();
                        for (int e = 0; e< nlGenre.getLength(); e++)
                        {
                            Element elemGenre = (Element) nlGenre.item(e);
                            String genreName = elemGenre.getTextContent().trim();

                            auxArray.add(genreName);
                            if(genreName.equals("pop"))
                            {
                                test = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if(test == true)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Array: " + auxArray);
                            System.out.println("Titulo: " +songTItle);

                            Song check = new Song(songTItle,auxArray);

                            System.out.println("Check SOng: " + check.getGenre());
                            Songs.add(check); //Here is the issue
                            System.out.println("ArraySize: " + Songs.size());

                            for(int z = 0; z<Songs.size();z++) {
                                String songTitle = Songs.get(z).getTitle();
                                System.out.println("ArrayTitulo: " + songTitle);
                                String songGenres;
                                for (int p = 0  ; p < Songs.get(z).getGenre().size();p++)
                                {
                                    songGenres = Songs.get(z).getGenre().get(p);
                                    System.out.println("ArrayGenreP: "+p + "  ArrayGenreZ: " + z +  "  Item: "+songGenres);

                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println("Genres: " + Songs.get(0).getGenre());
                            if(Songs.size()>1){
                                System.out.println("Genres: " + Songs.get(1).getGenre());

                            }
                            auxArray.clear();
                            test = false;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            NodeList nl_TVMLs = doc.getElementsByTagName("TVML");
            Element elemnt;

            for (int x=0; x < nl_TVMLs.getLength(); x++)
            {
                elemnt = (Element)nl_TVMLs.item(x);
                nextURL = elemnt.getTextContent().trim();
                System.out.println("Siguiente URL: " + nextURL);
            }
        }
        catch(SAXException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Excepction no well formed");
        }
        return nextURL;
    }

}
```

This, I think, it should add in the Songs array two songs, with two titles and, two genres the first one and three genres the second one, resulting in something like this:

Song Title: 8 Genres:[metal,pop,balad]

Song Title: 11 Genres:[funk,pop]

But the output I´m getting is:

Song Title: 8 Genres: [funk,pop]

Song Title: 11 Genres:[funk,pop]

Titles are correct, but genres are beeing overwrited by the last search in the loop.

My System.out.println() results are:

```
Array: [metal, pop, ballad]                 --> *First genre extracted array*

Title: 8
Check SOng: [metal, pop, ballad]            --> *Genres inside the Song object*

ArraySize: 1

ArrayTitulo: 8 --> Title is OK

ArrayGenreP: 0  ArrayGenreZ: 0  Item: metal  --> *P = genres index and Z = title index*

ArrayGenreP: 1  ArrayGenreZ: 0  Item: pop

ArrayGenreP: 2  ArrayGenreZ: 0  Item: ballad

Genres: [metal, pop, ballad]                 *--> Here is OK: Title 8 should have this 3 genres*

Array: [funk, pop]                           *--> This is the second array which is correct*

Title: 11                                    *--> This is the second title which is also ok*

Check SOng: [funk, pop]                      *--> This is the array stored in the new song object*

ArraySize: 2                                 *--> The new updated array size*

ArrayTitle: 8                                *--> The first title is correct*

ArrayGenreP: 0  ArrayGenreZ: 0  Item: funk   *--> Here is the problem, it overwrites the previous genres*

ArrayGenreP: 1  ArrayGenreZ: 0  Item: pop    * --> (but not the previous title)*

ArrayTitle: 11                                 --> Second title is also correct

ArrayGenreP: 0  ArrayGenreZ: 1  Item: funk  *-->These are the correct genres for song with title 11*

ArrayGenreP: 1  ArrayGenreZ: 1  Item: pop
Genres: [funk, pop]                         *--> Here should be [metal, pop, ballad] *

Genres: [funk, pop]                         *--> Here is OK*
```

And I´m completely stuck, I don´t know what else I can try, so some help would be very appreciated.

Maybe is something that has already beeing answered, if is the case I´m sorry, not my intention to waste anyones time.

Just in case I´m showing next the 2 .xml documents I created. The first one is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Music>
   <Year>2001</Year>
   <Album>
      <Name>uno</Name>
      <Country>spain</Country>
      <Titulo>titulo1</Titulo>
      <Song>
         <Title>1</Title>
         <Genre>pop</Genre>
         <Genre>rock</Genre>
      </Song>
      <Song>
         <Title>2</Title>
         <Genre>metal</Genre>
      </Song>
   </Album>
   <Album>
      <Name>dos</Name>
      <Country>england</Country>
      <Titulo>titulo2</Titulo>
      <Song>
         <Title>3</Title>
         <Genre>pop</Genre>
         <Genre>metal</Genre>
         <Genre>soul</Genre>
      </Song>
   </Album>
   <TVML>tmvl_02.xml</TVML>
</Music>
```

And the second one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Music>
   <Year>2003</Year>
   <Album>
      <Name>tres</Name>
      <Country>morocco</Country>
      <Titulo>titulo3</Titulo>
      <Song>
         <Title>4</Title>
         <Genre>pop</Genre>
         <Genre>soul</Genre>
      </Song>
      <Song>
         <Title>5</Title>
         <Genre>reggae</Genre>
      </Song>
      <Song>
         <Title>6</Title>
         <Genre>rock</Genre>
         <Genre>pop</Genre>
      </Song>
   </Album>
   <Album>
      <Name>cuatro</Name>
      <Country>france</Country>
      <Titulo>titulo4</Titulo>
      <Song>
         <Title>7</Title>
         <Genre>inide</Genre>
      </Song>
   </Album>
   <Album>
      <Name>cinco</Name>
      <Country>england</Country>
      <Titulo>titulo5</Titulo>
      <Song>
         <Title>10</Title>
         <Genre>rock</Genre>
      </Song>
      <Song>
         <Title>8</Title>
         <Genre>metal</Genre>
         <Genre>pop</Genre>
         <Genre>ballad</Genre>
      </Song>
      <Song>
         <Title>9</Title>
         <Genre>rock</Genre>
      </Song>
      <Song>
         <Title>11</Title>
         <Genre>funk</Genre>
         <Genre>pop</Genre>
      </Song>
   </Album>
</Music>
```

Thx in advance for your help and merry christmas.

Comment: Just a quick observation: in the Song class, you should copy the array that you pass in, because this could be a source of the sort of error you are seeing.  `genre = g;` change to `genre = new ArrayList<>( g );`

Comment: Your code creates one `ArrayList<String> auxArray` and shares that between all songs. Either create a new `ArrayList<String> auxArray` for each new `Song` or do as @markspace suggested and copy the list of genres in the `Song` constructor.

Comment: Yes, you are both right that was the problem. It´s working fine now. Thank you very much. You just saved my ass.